# EnableD2DSupport(); in MFC Direct2D Wrapper classes fails

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I want to make use of Direct2D Wrapper Classes in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional using Visual C++, so I checked various recipes on google how to do it. I already have a working Application in MFC and I want to rewrite the old GDI routines for faster operation. The first thing to do (as also stated by Microsoft) is to use EnableD2DSupport(); to initialize the D2D wrapper classes. However, it fails in

```
_AFX_D2D_STATE* pD2DState = AfxGetD2DState();
    if (pD2DState == NULL || !pD2DState->InitD2D())
    {
        // D2D is not supported by system
        return;
    }
```

which is a part of wincore.cpp, a part of the windows subsystem. I have already tried different parameters like EnableD2DSupport(TRUE) or EnableD2DSupport(TRUE, TRUE) - to no avail.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The documentation for [CWnd::EnableD2DSupport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#enabled2dsupport) states: *"Call this method before the main window is initialized."* We cannot see your code, and don't know, whether you adhere to this requirement.

Comment: Yes, it should be and I've tried - it fails anywhere.

Comment: Much as we'd like to believe you, the truth is in the code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Debug into InitD2D. You find the reason there. Either CoInitialize fails, or  D2D1.dll can't be loaded... or... or... or...

Comment: Okay, the right solution is in llnspectable first post: In my case it had to be called **without** parameters in CWinApp::InitInstance(). Still it is beyond me why it works differently for flaviu2's code. But that's another story. Case closed!

Comment: The case is neither closed, nor has it ever been opened. We still don't know your code, and we still don't know, why it fails. Your conclusion sounds like the entry level to cargo cult programming. Remember, if you don't know, why your code works, it doesn't.

Comment: I have not made any conclusion, I merely found a solution to my problem. If you're interested, I'd be happy to provide you with more details.

Comment: The implied conclusion is, that this were a solution. Calling a function without parameters, and calling that same function with parameters identical to the default arguments has the same effect. Claiming that you need to call that function **without** parameters sounds implausible. Then again, since we cannot see the code, all we can do is guess. I would guess that there is a bug in your code. If you want to fix that bug, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I do see your point. I really do. But please consider that assuming the bug in my code could be anywhere, there's somewhat of a tradeoff between minimal and complete. Verifiable for instance, would only be granted if you had access to the very same IDE and libraries I am currently using in the project file. That said, I'd still be happy to provide you with the code, but I suppose posting it here would defeat the purpose.

Comment: There is no tradeoff between *minimal* and *complete*. A [mcve] is defined as the least amount of code required to reproduce the issue. Reproducibility does not depend on the IDE. In fact, a successful strategy is to start from scratch, and not even use an IDE. Just start with an empty project, and take it from there. That requires that you know how to write MFC code without the help of an IDE.